# How to set an extension's configuration value in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use the `autosectionlabel_prefix_document` config value in the `autosectionlabel` extension described [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html#confval-autosectionlabel_prefix_document). I've loaded the extension in `conf.py`, and it works fine. Currently, I've tried adding the line:

```
autosectionlabel_prefix_document = True
```

to `conf.py`, but it's throwing the error message:

```
WARNING: undefined label: shaders:force shaders
(if the link has no caption the label must precede a section header)
```

Is there something I'm missing for configuring extensions? The documentation will be hosted on ReadTheDocs so I don't really have control over the extensions themselves, and it seems sloppy to have to do that anyway.

Just to be sure I have the syntax down in case that's the problem, I'm using

```
:ref:`shaders:force shaders`
```

which should be creating a link called `force shaders` to the subheading `force shaders` in the document `shaders.rst`.

Relevant versions:
Python 2.7
Sphinx 1.7.5
PyCharm 2018.1.4

Comment: Please clarify what "but it's not working" means (error message?). I cannot reproduce any problem with this (Sphinx 1.7.5). What version of Sphinx do you use?

Comment: Updated with relevant info

Comment: @mzjn after experimenting a little bit more, it looks like the autosectionlabel_prefix_document setting is being read because the error is different than it is if I just use autosectionlabel. But that still leaves me with an error I can't figure out. Is there something wrong with my syntax in the reST itself?

Comment: What's in shaders.rst? Is there a label in that document?

Comment: @mzjn Not that was premade. You can see the doc here: https://github.com/OpenMW/openmw/blob/master/docs/source/reference/modding/settings/shaders.rst

Comment: I have tried once again, but I still cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: In your conf.py, `autosectionlabel_prefix_document = True` is commented out, but I suppose that you know that already. https://github.com/OpenMW/openmw/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py

Comment: @mzjn Yes, I have it commented out until I can get it to work properly. Thanks for the help, I’ll try and experiment around with some fake docs to see if I can’t figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are using v1.7.5 while `autosectionlabel` appear in 1.4 the option `autosectionlabel_prefix_document` is only known in v 1.6 I had the same problem using an older version.

Comment: @marcz I haven't worked on this in a while, but I do know that I was aware of the version requirement and had updated to the latest version of Sphinx. We're using RTD to host, so that's the most important, but I can't even get it to work locally, so not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If `shaders.rst` is not in the root directory, you should prefix the filename with the path from the root directory. For example, if you have the following layout:

```
index.rst
/xdir
    main.rst
/ydir
    /zdir
        shaders.rst
```

Then you can reference the heading `Force Shaders` located in `shaders.rst` from `main.rst` as `` :ref:`ydir/zdir/shaders:force shaders` ``. (Works with sphinx-1.7.5 for me.)